# Why is my scanner producing all black images?

Tags: scanning

I have a HP PSC 1410 printer with a built-in scanner. I've been scanning documents and images with it for the last couple of years. Recently my scanner has stopped performing as expected and I can't scan or copy images\documents.

My problem is that every images\document I'm trying to scan - the result from the printer is a black page. I've been googling about this issue and couldn't find any helpful stuff beside replacing the whole printer - which is something i'm trying to avoid.

Any ideas ? I've read something about the shipping lock of the scanner but couldn't find any information about how to check it. Is this something that can be repaired, or do I need to get a new scanner?